# Need to create different sized circles using canvas arc

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

What I am trying to do is actually quiet easy, but I am new to javascript and very very new to canvas.

closePath will close my circle and that won't work, because I'm trying to make multiple circles inside of each.

All the data is fed via json.

An example of what I want to do is here. 
http://portfolio.amir-meshkin.com/linepie.png

**[js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ameshkin/afxu4rn1/5/)**

```
ctx.fill();    
ctx.closePath();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use arc() function and understand its working

Syntax of arc function is

```
arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
```

**Working Demo for your scenario :**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     
function draw(radius,color){

      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = radius;
      var startAngle =0;
      var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise = false;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
      context.lineWidth = 15;

      // line color
      context.strokeStyle = color;
      context.stroke();
}

draw(75,"yellow");
draw(65,"red");
draw(55,"green");
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderfully.

I've always said when it comes to PHP;

Once you understand the code, everything becomes easier.

I just need to apply what I know from PHP.

Comment: @my pleasure, you can accept it as an answer if it works for you :) and practice and learning will help without boundary of langaue php/js/etc